# How to scope variables in Manipulate (for Autorun)

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, localization, demonstrations

This question is connected with [that](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95896/how-to-scope-all-variables-in-manipulate) one (and all other connected). The purpose is to make a demonstration that has a Dynamic part among controls (I'm aware that it is not recommended, but nonetheless...). 
An artificial example.

```
Manipulate[
 f[x_] = 5 - a x;
 sol = First@Solve[f[x] == 0, x];

 Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 5}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 5}, 
 Epilog -> Text[x /. sol, {5., 5.}, {1., 1.}], (* !!! *)
 ImageSize -> Small]
 ,
 Dynamic[x /. sol],
 {sol, None},
 {a, 1, 2},
 TrackedSymbols -> {a},
 AutorunSequencing -> {2}
 ]
```

Assume that we need `sol` variable to use it in code repeatedly (say, `Solve` is huge and is used in many places). The code works fine unless one launches **Autorun** mode. Then periodically one may see the following.

[image]

**The question**: 1) how to avoid this problem given that we need to localize `sol` for Manipulate (I'm using `None` construct as being recommended).
2) explain a bit why does it happen (how does `Autorun` mode work in this case).

Comment: Try setting the initial value of `sol` to be a valid rule, i.e. use something like `{{sol, x -> 5}, None}`

Comment: @SimonWoods, thank you for comment, it solve the problem to hide `x\.` and applies the rule. In more involved cases (when `sol` is a result of many calculations with many controls) it might not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `Autorun` goes to repeat, there is a pause where the `Manipulate` appears in its initialized state.  When you specify a local variable thus

```
{sol, None}
```

the variables is automatically initialize to `0`.  To get something other than `x /. 0` to appear, you should explicitly initialize `sol`.  One of the following may be suitable (the output above the slider is noted in the commented code):

```
{{sol, {}}, None}          (* output: x *)
{{sol, {x -> 0}}, None}    (* output: 0 *)
{{sol, sol}, None}         (* output: 5 -- uses current value of sol *)
```

Whether one of these or another initialization seems most appropriate is a matter of style left to the user.

Comment: `{{sol, sol}, None}` this works nice, thank you.

Comment: @garej You're welcome and thanks for the accept.  `{{sol, sol}, None}` is the form I most often use.

Answer (score 3):

In your artificial example (at least), the problem can be avoided by eliminating `sol` altogether.

```
Manipulate[
  Dynamic @ Column[{
    Solve[f[x] == 0, x][[1, 1, 2]],
    Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> {0, 5}, ImageSize -> Small]
    }],
  {{a, 1}, 1, 2, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  Initialization :> (f[x_] := 5 - a x)]
```

[image: demo]

The moral of this story may be that your simplified example is too simple to represent your actual problem accurately.

"Everything should be made as simple as possible, but not simpler." - Albert Einstein

#### Update

This is my attempt to come up with an example where it is plausible for the root of `f[x] == 0` be captured in a localized dynamic variable.

```
Manipulate[
  Dynamic[
    root = Solve[f[x] == 0, x][[1, 1, 2]];
    Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 5},
      PlotRange -> {0, 5},
      Epilog -> Text[root, {5., 5.}, {1., 1.}],
      ImageSize -> Small]],
  {{a, 1}, 1, 2, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  {root, None},
  TrackedSymbols :> {a},
  AutorunSequencing -> {1},
  Initialization :> (f[x_] := 5 - a x)]
```

[image: demo2]

This example also avoids the problem you allude to and may be more applicable to your actual coding problem.

#### Update 2

The case you bring up in your comment, having the root appear in the control area rather than in the content pane, is another situation where a localized variable is unnecessary.

```
Manipulate[
  Dynamic @ Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> {0, 5}, ImageSize -> Small],
  {{a, 1}, 1, 2, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  Dynamic @ Row[{"root = ", Solve[f[x] == 0, x][[1, 1, 2]]}], 
  Initialization :> (f[x_] := 5 - a x)]
```

[image: demo3]

Comment: May I ask you to add a string to your code to make `root` changing on the control panel?